# Ist es schlechter Stil, »wegen + {Eigenname}+s« zu schreiben?

Tags: preposition, style, genitive, dative

Ist die Genitivkonstruktion bei der Präposition *wegen* für Eigennamen nicht besonders geeignet? Klingt (entweder schriftlich oder mündlich) einer der folgenden Sätze seltsam?

> 1. Wegen Christians sind alle hier. (Der hat Geburtstag.)
> 2. Wegen Herrn Schwarzkopfs sind alle hier. (Der hat Geburtstag.)

(Eventuelle Dativ-Umschreibung habe ich auch betrachtet, etwa

> 1'. Christian wegen sind alle hier.
>   2'. Herrn Schwarzkopf wegen sind alle hier.

aber ich würde gerne wissen, ob Genitiv hier ginge.)

Comment: Genau umgekehrt: _Christians wegen_ würde gerade noch gehen, aber _wegen Christians_ ist völlig ungrammatisch.

Comment: Ungrammatisch nicht (wegen des Geburtstagskinds → wegen Christians) doch extrem ungebräuchlich.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Im Abschnitt [Allein stehendes Nomen im Singular](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Genitiv.html#Anchor-Allein-49575) auf canoo.net heißt es: Unflektiert, wenn das Nomen **nicht** durch einen Artikel oder Adjektiv begleitet wird.

Das Gleiche findet man auch noch mal beim Eintrag zu *[wegen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Genitiv.html#Anchor-wegen-58500)*.

Folglich:

> wegen Christian, *aber* wegen des großen Christians

Etwas schwieriger ist da die Frage mit der Kombination Titel *Herr/Frau* plus Name.

Nach der obigen Regel müsste es

> wegen Herr Schwarzkopf, *aber* wegen des großen Herrn Schwarzkopfs

lauten. In der Praxis ist aber der Dativ (auch ohne Artikel) gängig, also "wegen Herrn Schwarzkopf". Und das Genitiv-s fällt gerne weg: "wegen des großen Herrn Schwarzkopf".
Eine aussagekräftige Onlinesuche ist mir nicht gelungen. Auch sonst bleibe ich Referenzen dazu leider schuldig.
Ich würde aber behaupten, in der Alltagssprache ist beides durchaus 'richtig'. In der Schriftsprache würde ich im Zweifel zu einer anderen Formulierung greifen. Hier kann man sich zu Nutzen machen, dass bei dem "Nomen + Nomen"-Konstrukt "Christians Geburtstag" und "Herrn Schwarzkopfs Geburtstag" der Genitiv unabdingbar ist, und zwar unabhängig von der Präposition. Daher heißt es ausnahmslos:

> wegen Christians Geburtstag
>   wegen Herrn Schwarzkopfs Geburtstag

Comment: _Herr Name_ ist aber ein Spezialfall, bei dem beide Teile dekliniert werden. _Herrn Name_ ist Dativ, _Herrn Names_ ist Genitiv; bei _des Herrn Name_ ist der Artikel der entscheidende Unterschied.

Comment: @chirlu Hast du eine Referenz dazu. "Wegen Herrn Names" klingt ziemlich falsch. Es sei denn, es folgt ein Nomen. "Wegen Herrn Müllers Geburtstag". Aber genau dann würde man auch beim Christian das "s" wieder anhängen. "Wegen Christians Geburtstag". – Das hatte ich soweit aber der Einfachheit wegen weggelassen. Ich kann das noch ergänzen. Zu klären wäre nur noch, ob es noch einen Beleg gibt, dass "Wegen Herrn Schwarzkopfs sind alle hier." doch richtig ist. Was ich aber bezweifel. Gehört habe ich es zumindest noch nicht. Zumal dann auch "Wegen Christians sind alle hier" richtig sein müsste.

Comment: Mein Punkt war erst einmal nur, daß dieser Abschnitt falsch ist: *Vorweg erstmal, nicht der Name, sondern der Titel wird flektiert. Das -s am Nachnamen ist sicher falsch. Herrn signalisiert schon den Kasus.* Ich bin mir selbst nicht sicher, warum _wegen Christians_ und _wegen Herrn Schwarzkopfs_ nicht gehen; aber _wegen Christian_ und _wegen Herrn Schwarzkopf_ sind keine *s*-losen Genitive, sondern schlicht Dative.

Comment: @chirlu Und jetzt hab ich geschnallt, warum es die Versionen "wegen Herr X" und "wegen Herrn X" gibt. "Wegen Christian" und "Wegen Herr X" sind nicht Dativ, sondern unflektiert. Aber nicht untypisch ist ja sowas wie "Wegen dem Christian", "Wegen dem Herrn X" (->Dativ). Und gerne lässt man dann doch das unhübsche "dem" weg, und zack, landet man bei "Wegen Christian" (identisch zur unflektierten Version) und "Wegen Herrn X". – Von s-losen Genitiv habe ich übrigens nie geredet. Aber ich bleibe (vorerst) bei dem Punkt, dass der Genitiv im "Herrn" einen erneuten Genitiv im Namen überflüssig macht.

Comment: Mal weg von _wegen_ mit seinen komplizierten Genitiv/Dativ-Regeln; bei _Herrn Müllers Auto_ kannst du doch das *-s* nicht weglassen, trotz _Herrn_. – Übrigens, _wegen Herr Müller_ wäre für mich schlicht falsch.

Comment: @chirlu Der Punkt geht an dich. Es müsste tatsächlich korrekt "wegen des Herrn Schwarzkopfs" heißen, wenn mit Artikel oder Adjektiv aufgenommen wird. Die Praxis belehrt uns oft eines Anderen, nämlich, dass das "-s" nicht angehängt wird. Ich hab die Antwort mal dahingehend angepasst.

Comment: Nein, Artikel sind wieder etwas anderes, wie ich oben schon sagte. :-)

Comment: Ich tendiere dazu, *wegen Herrn Weißhaupt* zu sagen (hier wird mir zu viel geschwarzkopft ;)), also den Namen im Dativ zu haben. Christians Dativ fällt nicht weiter auf, weil der Dativ im Namen unmarkiert ist. *Wegen Herr Weißhaupt* klingt für mich dagegen falsch. Demnach würde ich davon ausgehen, dass es hier *nicht* eine unflektierte Form sondern eine Dativform ist.